# SQL join along with aggregate function

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions

I need to solve the below query. I'm not able to figure out which join to use. Is there any particular way to figure out which join to use.

By joining the customer table and the transaction table, write a SQL query to sum the Order Value split by gender

I tried the following query:

```
select sum(t.amt_spent),c.gender 
from customer c
join transaction t
    on c.cust_id=t.cust_id
group by e.gender
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the tables structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are referencing a non-existent table alias "e" in your GROUP BY clause. Try this:

```
select sum(t.amt_spent),c.gender 
from customer c
join transaction t
    on c.cust_id = t.cust_id
group by c.gender
```

Comment: thank you so much. but inner join the right join to be used in this situation?

Comment: You can switch to a left join if you want to see customers with $0 spent.